# go - converting if statements into short statement

Tags: go

I have many if statements

```
anotherName : ="ABC"

if len(dict) > 0 {
    if _, ok := dictA["Name"]; ok {
        if fName, ok := dataDict["Name"]; ok {
            if fName== "SAM" {
                if len(dict) > 1 {
                    mainDict[anotherName] = dict
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I dont want to use so many if statements. I want to use operators but I am not able to use them here in this scenario.

Can anyone let me know.

Comment: You could do things different depending on your surrounding. Is this the only code in a function or in a loop?

Comment: What do you need the two `len`s for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options I can think of. Not sure if you like it better or if it works in your code:

1) in a function (in a loop use `break`):

```
anotherName : ="ABC"
if len(dict) = 0 {
    return
}
if _, ok := dictA["Name"]; !ok {
    return
}
if fName, ok := dataDict["Name"]; !ok {
    return
}
if fName== "SAM" && len(dict) > 1 {
   mainDict[anotherName] = dict
}
```

2) not using check for `ok` but check for `nil`:

```
anotherName : ="ABC"

if len(dict) > 0 && dictA["Name"] != nil && dataDict["Name"] != nil && dataDict["Name"] == "SAM" && len(dict) > 1 {
  mainDict[anotherName] = dict
}
```

Maybe you can also eliminate one of the checks for `len(dict) > 0` and `len(dict) > 1`.